# Mailmerge - Individual PDFs - Top 2 Rows NOT header

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

Sourced from https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

I'm using the code as it stands for the individual PDFs on Word and I have 2 issues I can't resolve.

The code works (Praise Macropod!) however my excel file has 2 of the top rows before the header starts, so I cannot pull the .datafield from anything that isn't just the very first column as that top row is formatted as a merge and centre. This is a client document so I have to work with their data as given, I can't just remove those top 2 rows, I know that would solve it.

One idea I can't figure out is how to get the last line in this With:

```
  With .DataSource
    .FirstRecord = i
    .LastRecord = i
    .ActiveRecord = i
    If Trim(.DataFields("Last_Name")) = "" Then Exit For
    'StrFolder = .DataFields("Folder") & "\"
    StrName = .DataFields("Last_Name") & "_" & .DataFields("First_Name")
```

to pull in more than one field, I want it save as lastname_firstname.pdf but I tried a few things here

- .DataFields("Last_Name")  - this works.
- .DataFields("Last_Name")  & "_" & .DataFields("F2")- this doesn't work, well it does but then it errored out after a single one came out, save a single PDF file.

Is there a way to use the datafield as a sort of +1, IE I want A2_B2.pdf, can I write A2 & A2+1 in a way to get B2?

Other possibility is to reference the start point, in that case I don't know enough to add like the "Finish & Merge" button has the option From and does a range, that would help perhaps but I still need to sort out the datafields, that would have to work with that shift of sorts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the first 'issue' you might use something like:

```
Sub Merge_To_Individual_Files()
'Sourced from: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Excel object model.
'See under the VBE's Tools|References.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFolder As String, StrName As String, MainDoc As Document, i As Long, j As Long
Dim StrMMSrc As String, StrSht As String, StrTxt As String
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource
  StrMMSrc = .Name: StrSht = Split(Split(.QueryString, "`")(1), "$")(0)
End With
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application, xlWkBk As Excel.Workbook, xlWkSht As Excel.Worksheet
xlApp.Visible = False
Set xlWkBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMru:=False)
Set xlWkSht = xlWkBk.Names(StrTbl).RefersTo
StrTxt = xlWkSht.Range("F2").Text
xlWkBk.Close: xlApp.Quit: Set xlWkSht = Nothing: Set xlWkBk = Nothing
Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument
...
```

I have no idea what your other 'issue' is about. In any event, you're supposed to limit questions to one per thread.